# Упорядочить соответственные элементы в двух массивах

Tags: java, массивы

К примеру, есть массив `{1, 4, 2, 3}`. И есть `{a, c, g, r}`.

Мне нужно первый массив выровнять по возрастанию (1 в начало, 2 за ним, и тд).
И соответственные элементы второго надо сортировать соответственно первому массиву.
В итоге в первом должно получиться `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, а во втором `{a, g, r, c}`.

Вопрос: как это реализовать на Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если у вас данные в двух массивах связаны друг с другом, то я бы посоветовал создать класс, объединяющий эти данные. Затем сортировать массив объектов с помощью компаратора.

Также можно использовать коллекцию `Map`, если данные в цифровом массиве уникальны (не повторяются).

Если же это не подходит, то можно посмотреть в сторону решения, которое было описано на [eng stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688736/5464893).

Пример класса, объединяющего данные:

```
public class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
        public int numValue;
        public char charValue;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Data o)
        {
            if (numValue < o.numValue)
                return -1;
            else if(numValue > o.numValue)
                return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    }
```

В numValue помещаем 1 элемент цифрового массива, в charValue - соответствующую букву. Создаем массив из объектов Data и сортируем его с помощью Collections.sort() (или Arrays.sort()).